# Passing a function thact changes state to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am doing a component right now, and ran into an issue. I have a useState in my parent component

```
const [selectedVacation, setSelectedVacation] = useState(null);
```

And also a function, that takes an argument and puts it inside the state

```
const selectVacation = (vacation) => setSelectedVacation(vacation);
```

Then, there is a component, to which I pass my function, which should update the state

```
<AdminCatalog
  vacations={vacations}
  selectVacation={selectVacation}
/>
```

Inside this component, I map through vacations and render a component for each of those, and want to update my state in parent component, when uer clicks on one of these components.

```
<ItemsWrap>
  {vacations?.map((vacation) => (
    <AdminItem
      onClick={selectVacation(vacation)}
      key={vacation._id}
      vacation={vacation}
    />
  ))}
</ItemsWrap>
```

However, this doesn't work and I do not really understand why. Could anyone please assist me with solving this problem?

Inside AdminItem component, there is another component AdminSelect

```
    <AdminSelect
      photo={updatedPhoto}
      title={user.name}
      startDate={moment(vacation.startDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
      endDate={moment(vacation.endDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
      date={date}
    />
```

Comment: What do you have inside your `AdminItem`?

Comment: @RyanLe There is another component, which destructures vacations and uses properties as props.

Comment: Could you please provide it in the question? And you want to have updated state when the user click on `AdminItem` component?

Comment: @RyanLe I have added another component. Yes, exactly, I want it to be updated when the component is clicked, so that *vacation* is passed into useState

Comment: Try to wrap your `AdminItem` content around an HTML Element. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You assign to the `onClick` props of `AdminItem` the result of `selectVacation(vacation)`. Instead you need to pass a reference to a function (not the result of its evaluation), which may be defined with a fat arrow function :

```
<ItemsWrap>
  {vacations?.map((vacation) => (
    <AdminItem
      onClick={() => selectVacation(vacation)}
      key={vacation._id}
      vacation={vacation}
    />
  ))}
</ItemsWrap>
```

Also note that the selectVacation is useless, you can directly use setSelectedVacation.

Answer (score 0):

**`onClick` event is not available on Reactjs Component by default your will need to pass that event from an HTML Element**

Inside your `AdminItem`, wrap your children components with a html element:

**Something like this:**

```
export default function AdminItem({onclick}) {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => onClick()}>{children}</div>
  );
}
```

By doing that, `onClick` event from HTML Element will be passing to your parent component.

---

Although, the `onClick` event on a `div` element is not recommended. Try to put your children inside a `<button>` or `<a>` tag, but you will have to deal with some eslint rules and HTML standard.